# How is the amount of battle points earned at the end of the game counted?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In PUBG, you are rewarded with Battle Point (BP) every match you play.

There seems to be a couple of factors that decide how much you receive:

- Position
- Damage done
- Kills

But how are they mixed to give that final number of points you earn? Are there other criteria tracked?

EDIT: From personal experience, this seems to be the rule:

- 20pts per player kill
- 1pt per 4 damage done (making 20for a full kill, might include damage to vehicules)
- Placement seems to be exponential, starting at about 50 for placements over 60-70, and about 800 for a chicken dinner
- There might be something else at play, making the amount of points variable... maybe time survived?

Nothing here is exact or even confirmed, so thats why I'm not throwing it in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PUBG Wiki](http://pubg.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_Point) and [this site](https://samurai-gamers.com/playerunknowns-battlegrounds-pubg/battle-points-bp-rewards/):

- Single player BP scales up to 800BP for win
- Duo up to 400BP/player for win
- Squad up to 200BP/player for win
- Total amount of kills a player has made (20/pk solo, 15/pk duo, 10/pk squad)
- Total amount of damage a player outputs (approx. 1BP per 5 damage)

EDIT - conflicting sources, total kills claimed to be 20/pk regardless of mode by samurai-gamers.com

Comment: Seems I was not far from what I tought was the rule :p

Comment: I believe its 20 points a kill no matter the game mode.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, need to work on my formatting! This may have been changed at some point, I've just done some research and come across some screenshots at 15/pk duo [example](https://rebelsofcarnage.com/index.php/en/775-sniper-and-svntwoo-back-to-back-chicken-dinners-pubg)

Comment: Those screenshots are from August.  The game has been updated many times since then, but it's possible.  I'll have to see for myself and report back.